# I am not able to add picture in vs code html showing error not able to resolve it but this same question working on notepad how?

Tags: html

[image]

[image: re]

I am not able to add a picture  in vs code HTML showing error not able to resolve it but this same question working on notepad how?
how can I fix this and how can I add pictures to the file

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="./girl.jpg" alt="profile pic"/>
```

Please correct the image path. Use below mention method

Answer (score 0):

When assets like images is placed beside of your project, you can use **A relative URL** like `src="girl.jpg"`.

For more information look *Absolute URLs vs relative URLs* in this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL).

Now, your img tag must change to this:

```
<img src="girl.jpg" alt="profile_pic" />
```